# An adjective meaning something is imposed in a country by another country?

Tags: word-request

> This coup was run in this country by another country. It is a -----
>   coup.

What word to put in the blank? I want an adjective meaning that the something, such as a coup, is imposed/run/planned in a country by another country. Is *foreign-made* a good choice here? Any better suggestion?

Comment: Simply **"foreign"** or something like **"outsider"** etc

Comment: I think *foreign-backed* would also be a good suggestion. Even better if you know the country. *US-backed* or *UK-orchestrated* for instance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_involvement_in_regime_change)

Comment: @Smock Good idea if you give this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A very good answer in the comments:

> I think foreign-backed would also be a good suggestion. Even better if you know the country. US-backed or UK-orchestrated for instance ([en.wikipedia.org/wiki/…](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_involvement_in_regime_change)) – Smock

Comment: Isn't it better that Smock mention this as an answer?

Comment: I don't mind (it is attributed)